# No parametless constructor defined Hangfire Ninject

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, ninject, hangfire, .net-4.6.1, hangfire.ninject

I'm having a problem activating instance of my class with no parametless constructor defined.

The constructor:

```
public HangfireExecutor(ICommandDispatcher commandDispatcher, IQueryDispatcher queryDispatcher, IMapper mapper)
```

How I register and configure Hangfire (three dots are used instead of sensitive info):

```
[assembly: OwinStartupAttribute(typeof(Web2.Startup))]
    public partial class Startup

    private IAppBuilder _app;
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        _app = app;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("...");

        _app.UseHangfireDashboard("/...", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter() },
            AppPath = "/Identity/Create"
        });

        _app.UseHangfireServer();

        _app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    }
```

Registration in IoC container:

```
public partial class Startup
{
...
protected IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    var kernel = new StandardKernel();
    ...
    kernel.Bind<HangfireExecutor>().ToSelf().InBackgroundJobScope();
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);
    return kernel;
```

The error:

```
System.MissingMethodException
No parameterless constructor defined for this object hangfire ninject System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance
System.MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for this object
at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic)
at System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type)
at Hangfire.JobActivator.ActivateJob(Type jobType)
at Hangfire.JobActivator.SimpleJobActivatorScope.Resolve(Type type)
at Hangfire.Server.CoreBackgroundJobPerformer.Perform(PerformContext context)
```

For me it looks like the Hangfire does not use Ninject activator (?) but I don't know why.

I've followed both tutorials: on Hangfire site and Hangfire.Ninject github and several github repos and SO questions.

Instatiating other classes not used by Hangfire works well; also instatiating Hangfire executor with parametless constructor works properly.

I'm using:

- ASP .NET MVC 5
- .NET Framework 4.6.1,
- Hangfire 1.6.21
- Hangfire.Ninject 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As method  `_app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);` does not create kernel (just keeps delegate to the metod creating the kernel) the correct order of commands in Hangfire configuration in my case should be:

```
public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        ConfigureAuth(app);
        _app = app;

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("...");

        _app.UseHangfireDashboard("/...", new DashboardOptions
        {
            Authorization = new[] { new HangfireDashboardAuthorizationFilter() },
            AppPath = "/Identity/Create"
        });

        _app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel);
    }
```

and then at the end of `CreateKernel` method:

```
kernel.Bind<HangfireExecutor>().ToSelf().InBackgroundJobScope();

        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseNinjectActivator(kernel);

        _app.UseHangfireServer();

        return kernel;
```

Now Hangfire started resolving dependencies. I think that it is important to create kernel as soon after starting the app as possible - otherwise Hangfire may not be initialized and background jobs will not be executed.